# Recursive binary search python

Tags: python, binary-search

I've been trying to write binary search recursively. When I do this using the list[:] syntax I don't get the intended results with several errors coming up or not getting the correct values.

```
def binary_search(arr, val):

  left = 0 
  right = len(arr)-1
  mid = (left + right)//2

  #Go through the array
   if (val == arr[mid]):
     return mid
   #Check right side of arr
   if (val > arr[mid]):
     return binary_search(arr[mid+1:], val)
   #Check left side of arr
   return binary_search(arr[:mid], val)
```

EDIT: Example inputs and outputs

```
arr1 =[]
for i in range(10):
    arr1.append(i)

for i in range(10):
    print(binary_search(arr1,i))
```

I expect to get something like `'0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'` but get `'0,1,0,0,4,None ,None,2,0,0'`

Comment: Can you give example inputs and show what your function outputs compared to what you expected?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to have a `while` loop that contains an unconditional return. You'll never loop more than once, that way. (posting this as a comment and not an answer because I don't have any specific recommendations about what you should be doing instead)

Comment: @glibdud I made the necessary edits

Comment: @Kevin your'e right. THe while loop is unnecessary so I took that out, but I still get the same errors

Comment: See [**`bisect`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems. First one is a typo, where you say

```
if (val > mid):
```

you should say

```
if (val > arr[mid]):
```

Since you're comparing the value and not the index.

Second one is more subtle... when you check the right side of the array, in:

```
return binary_search(arr[mid+1:], val)
```

The subarray you're passing to the recursive call (`arr[mid+1:]`) already starts in the middle of the array, that means the result of that recursive call will return the index of the element **in the subarray**.  So you need to add the index delta you used to split the array, to have a index based on the full array again:

```
return binary_search(arr[mid+1:], val) + (mid + 1)
```

Here's the full code for completeness:

```
def binary_search(arr, val):
  left = 0 
  right = len(arr)-1
  mid = (left + right)//2

  #Go through the array
  if (val == arr[mid]):
     return mid
   #Check right side of arr
  if (val > arr[mid]):
     return binary_search(arr[mid+1:], val) + (mid + 1)
   #Check left side of arr
  return binary_search(arr[:mid], val)
```

Comment: God like god like god like.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing `val` to `mid`, instead of to `arr[mid]`. Also, it would read nicer if you made the **ifs** mutually exclusive. Also, as per nosklo's answer below, you need to add the index offset for the greater than case:

```
#Go through the array
if (val == arr[mid]):
    return mid
#Check right side of arr
elif (val > mid):
    return binary_search(arr[mid+1:], val) + (mid + 1)
#Check left side of arr
else:
    return binary_search(arr[:mid], val)
```

Comment: That's not enough to fix it, see my answer

Comment: @nosklo - thanks, I still  prefer my version with the `elif` / `else`.

Comment: Sure! I also prefer if/elif - I like to copy the exact OP's code to help them understand where their process of thought went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here, more generic binary search recursive function, that returns `None` if the key not found.

```py
def binary_search(arr, val):
    mid = len(arr) // 2
    if (val == arr[mid]):
        return mid
    if mid == 0:
        return None
    if (val > arr[mid]):
        call_back = binary_search(arr[mid+1:], val)
        return call_back + mid + 1 if call_back is not None else None
    return binary_search(arr[:mid], val)
```

Result:

```py
arr = list(range(10))
for i in range(15):
    print(binary_search(arr, i))
```

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
None
None
None
None
None
```